# Damp wall ignored, why?

Tags: dwarf-fortress, dwarf-fortress-premium

I took as granted that Miners always detected damp walls and stopped mining in these cases.

But a miner did not detect, or just decided to ignore, an obvious damp wall, and [created a leak that led to a massive flooding of the Fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/402542/how-do-i-revert-the-flood/).

How is this possible? As most strange behaviors on Dwarf Fortress are not bugs, but purposely programmed by the developers, I would like to understand the factors that leads me to not trusting my Miners common sense anymore.

[image]

**Version:** 0.50 (Steam).

Comment: _"trusting my Miners common sense "_ That's your _first_ problem :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Assuming that it works the same as in the ASCII version: only newly discovered damp tiles cause dwarves to cancel mining. If you tell them to mine through a tile that you already know is damp, they do it. The game assumes that you *want* to deliberately mine into the river and flood your caves.

In the linked question it was clarified that this is an above-ground river (viewed from underground). The river was revealed since the start of the game, and so were the damp tiles around its edge.

Comment: Yes, it works the same as in the ASCII version. This is why nothing beats constant vigilance and checking their work over and over.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Technically you just have to be vigilant when designating tiles to be mined.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Do you want floods? Because that's how you get floods. Tiles can become damp _after_ you designate them for mining, for reasons unrelated to _that_ project. And in case of revealed tile becoming damp, it does not cancel mining designation.

Comment: Oh interesting, dampness is checked at designation (even on unknown tiles), not at the moment of actual mining? Oof.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni designation cancellation happen when previously hidden tile becomes visible and it is damp/warm. If tile is already visible, designation won't be cancelled in any case. I learned this the hard way after digging throug wall which led to the hidden part of the caverns which I flooded several minutes before that.